# How can I make horizontal drop down menu when button clicked?

Tags: css, qt

I'm trying to make drop-down popup menu with horizontal direction when a QPushButton is clicked,
with menu item being only icon, without short cut text and menu item text.
Is it possible in Qt?
I've tried google search, but I can't find the solution, also not in Qt documentation.

In ascii drawing horizontal drop-down menu is appears like this below a button:

button
| Img0 | Img1 | Img2 | Img3 |

I've coded the relevant parts like this:

```
QImage sourceImage(":/Res/layout/layout_wide_select.png");
int w = sourceImage.width() / 7;
int h = sourceImage.height();

QImage lay5= sourceImage.copy(0, 0, w, h);
QImage lay7= sourceImage.copy(w, 0, w, h);
....
m_menuWide = new QMenu(this);
QAction *actLay5 = m_menuWide->addAction(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(lay5)), "5view");
QObject::connect(actLay5, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(onSplitWideButtonClicked()));
actLay5->setData(QVariant(0));
QAction *actLay7 = m_menuWide->addAction(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(lay7)), "7view");
QObject::connect(actLay7, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(onSplitWideButtonClicked()));
actLay7->setData(QVariant(1));
...
m_btnSplitWide->setMenu(m_menuWide);
```

It seems that there is no method like setMenuDireciton() in QMenu, or and no 
QMenu property usable in QMenu style...

I will be very appreciated if anyone know the solution..

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [QWidgetAction](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidgetaction.html)
This will add widget to your QMenu. You can create your QWidget (maybe toolbar) of your action and put it on QWidgetAction. And add the widgetaction to your QMenu.
Sample code :

```
QMenu menu;
QToolBar toolbar;
toolbar.addAction("A");
toolbar.addAction("B");
QWidgetAction act(&toolbar);
act.setDefaultWidget(&toolbar);
menu.addAction(&act);
menu.exec();
```

You can change the action "A" and "B" only with your icon.

Comment: Thank you! I've recoded as your suggestion, and successfully got horizontal popup window.

Comment: If it works, can you please set as fixed. There is a "check sign" left side of my answer, please check the sign so this thread will be closed as answered.